# Hibernate 4 bytecode enhancement not working for dirty checking optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, byte-code-enhancement, dirty-checking

I am using the Hibernate 4.3.6 and I made use of the latest [Maven bytecode enhancement](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-4-bytecode-enhancement/) to instrument all entities for self dirtiness awareness.

I added the maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and I see my entities are being enhanced:

```
@Entity
public class EnhancedOrderLine
implements ManagedEntity, PersistentAttributeInterceptable, SelfDirtinessTracker
{
    @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private Long number;
  private String orderedBy;
  private Date orderedOn;

  @Transient
  private transient PersistentAttributeInterceptor $$_hibernate_attributeInterceptor;

  @Transient
  private transient Set $$_hibernate_tracker;

  @Transient
  private transient CollectionTracker $$_hibernate_collectionTracker;

  @Transient
  private transient EntityEntry $$_hibernate_entityEntryHolder;

  @Transient
  private transient ManagedEntity $$_hibernate_previousManagedEntity;

  @Transient
  private transient ManagedEntity $$_hibernate_nextManagedEntity;

  ...
```

While debugging, I am checking `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener#dirtyCheck` method:

```
        if ( entity instanceof SelfDirtinessTracker ) {
            if ( ( (SelfDirtinessTracker) entity ).$$_hibernate_hasDirtyAttributes() ) {
                dirtyProperties = persister.resolveAttributeIndexes( ( (SelfDirtinessTracker) entity ).$$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes() );
            }
        }
```

and the `$$_hibernate_hasDirtyAttributes()` always returns **false**.

This is because `$$_hibernate_attributeInterceptor` is always null, so when setting any property:

```
private void $$_hibernate_write_number(Long paramLong)
{
 if (($$_hibernate_getInterceptor() == null) || ((this.number == null) || (this.number.equals(paramLong))))
  break label39;
 $$_hibernate_trackChange("number");
 label39: Long localLong = paramLong;
 if ($$_hibernate_getInterceptor() != null)
  localLong = (Long)$$_hibernate_getInterceptor().writeObject(this, "number", this.number, paramLong);
 this.number = localLong;
}
```

because the `$$_hibernate_getInterceptor()` is null the trackChange will be bypassed, hence the bytecode enhancement will not resolve the dirty properties and the default deep-comparison algorithm will be used.

What am I missing? How can I get the `$$_hibernate_attributeInterceptor` to be properly set so that the dirty properties are tracked by the bytecode instrumentation methods?

Comment: Is that enhancement is a byte code enhancement how did you get that source for class EnhancedOrderLine.

Comment: Follow the JIRA issue link at the beginning of the question.

Comment: when I look at the link you referred I saw those guys using it in compile phase. Can you try again  in compile-test phase ?

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: At the end of this article they mention something very close to what you are asking here http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-bytecode-enhancement

Comment: That's because I wrote that article too ;)

Comment: can you post the solution if its found

Comment: There is no solution to it yet, the Hibernate 5 might add the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hibernate 5 fixes this issue](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-enable-bytecode-enhancement-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/) and now the dirty checking for a setter looks like this:

```
public void $$_hibernate_write_title(String paramString)
{
    if (!EqualsHelper.areEqual(this.title, paramString)) {
      $$_hibernate_trackChange("title");
    }
    this.title = paramString;
}

public void $$_hibernate_trackChange(String paramString)
{
    if (this.$$_hibernate_tracker == null) {
      this.$$_hibernate_tracker = new SimpleFieldTracker();
    }
    this.$$_hibernate_tracker.add(paramString);
}
```

So, the solution is an upgrade to Hibernate 5.

Comment: Hi Mihalcea, I was trying to do bytecode enhancement for my model classes (which are in XML mappings) with using Hibernate 5 but not able to convert model classes like above one. Am I missing anything here or is byte code enhancement will work only for annotations?

Comment: As far as I know, it should work with XML mappings too.

Comment: I tried with all options but no luck. I saw your example and tried the same but no luck for Hibernate 5 version.

Comment: Strange. It works just fine on [my repo](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence).

Comment: It is working for annotations but not for XML mappings. My project table mappings are defined in XML file.

Comment: Add a replicating test case and open a JIRA issue then ;)

Comment: Yeah. I did that one. Here is the [link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10622). The defect is assigned but don't see any updates after that. Will update you if I get any update :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will give you the correct behaviour in all situations, but you can generally get the dirty checks working (at least according to some skeleton code I tested it with) by doing the following:

1. Register an entity listener by adding `@EntityListeners(YourListener.class)` to the entities
2. Add implementations for all `@Pre`/`@Post` (eg `@PrePersist` etc) methods to your `YourListener.class` where you check if the entity is an instance of `PersistentAttributeInterceptable`, and if it is just call `$$_hibernate_setInterceptor` on it with a custom `PersistentAttributeInterceptor` that just returns the new values (that particular behaviour may need refined for general use, i'm not sure, but it was good enough to catch it for my simple tests - you know more about general use cases for the interceptor than me).

A hack solution for what is clearly a bug.

Comment: I am more interested in Hibernate built-in support for that. You can customize the dirty checking but that's not what I asked for.

Comment: I would say I was just configuring Hibernate to ensure enhanced entities have a very plain interceptor, which the enhanced code relies on being present. I do not see where I am customizing the dirty checking. That will still be handled by $$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes/$$_hibernate_hasDirtyAttributes will it not ? As you pointed out the enhanced code requires an interceptor to be present to work. There may be another way to configure Hibernate to provide one, but providing it via entity annotations is just another way of doing it.

Comment: I don't understand your point. The interceptor does not need to handle any dirty checking, as far as I can see you can just set it to always return the new value. Then the enhanced dirty checking works properly. By configuring via annotations a simple dummy interceptor, the enhanced dirty checking works.  I thought this was what you wanted. Otherwise this question is just a bug report: "The enhanced code requires an interceptor - either it shouldn't or Hibernate should supply a dummy, without explicitly being told to via annotations".

Comment: I'll test it and let you know.